# Error when upgrading to WebAPI 2.1 XmlDocumentationProvider does not implement interface member GetDocumentation

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I'm following the tutorial here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#download

I created an MVC Web Api project in Visual Studio 2012 (.NET Framework 4.5), and ran this command in my NuGet Package Manager Console Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

When I tried to build my project, I get this error:

```
'CommonServices.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member 
    'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetDocumentation(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor)' c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CommonServices\CommonServices\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs

'CommonServices.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member 
    'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetResponseDocumentation(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor)' c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CommonServices\CommonServices\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got the same problem when getting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.

At Nuget Package Manager Console write this:

```
Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProjectNameGoesHere' -Reinstall
```

This will update all your packages and it will solve your problem.I hope it helps

Comment: This is a better answer as it clearly gives the command to do the job.

Comment: I used the command mentioned above and everything was installed and updated properly. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: I ran Update-Package, but I am getting the same errors as well.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31472485/4480300) answer does.

Comment: Yes. This did not help me too. The answer given by Alex worked well.

Comment: I installed this to support CORS: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and that's when I get the error. Please help.

Answer (score 22):

You can fix this issue by running the following two commands in the Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage
```

This will install the required HelpPage components which are missing. You can then run an update on all NuGet Packages in your project in order to verify that all packages are up to date.

```
Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProject' -Reinstall
```

(Remember to replace YourProject with the name of your actual project)

Update: If you continue to receive errors after building and running, you may need to update the Razor references in your Web.Config file to look like this

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: The answer marked as the solution did not resolve this for me. The Install-Package HelpPage in this answer resolved it.

Comment: Installing HelpPage helped here as well.

Comment: This Answer resolved my problem not the answer marked as solution.

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error. This is how fixed it.

Add these two methods to the `~\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs` class

```
    public virtual string GetDocumentation(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public virtual string GetResponseDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Obviously, I wouldn't use this solution with real-world Enterprise applications since I don't know if this breaks anything important. I would only do this if you're running a test project or something. (**although it looks like only some kind of Documentation is the only thing which is affected**)

Answer (score 7):

Even after I run `Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProjectNameGoesHere' -Reinstall`, still got the same problem.

run `PM> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I was getting build error whenever i am adding any new package from the NuGet Package Manager. **I fixed it by deleting the file** (~\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs) from the project and it worked for me.