# C# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API XmlDocumentationProvider error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

When working with a `Web API` template in an `ASP.NET MVC 4` project, trying to compile I get this error:

> 'Solution.Web.Api.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetResponseDocumentation
>    (System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor)'

It seems the class doesn't implement all interface methods. However, I didn't create any code yet or apply any code change to the default project.

Would you know what is causing this problem?

Comment: Alberto, if you start a new project I'd recommend moving to MVC/Web API 5.12.

Comment: I have fixed it by deleting the file in this way.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51184698/4627336

Answer (score 17):

Mark's answer to update the Web API Help Page worked for me. Here are the commands I ran to make it happen:

**In Visual Studio 2013:**

- TOOLS -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console
- Paste the following into the Package Manager Console:

`Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`

- Hit Enter, cross fingers, and post alternative solutions if you find them!

Answer (score 3):

The error is somewhere in the Web Api HelpPage. This is just a nuget package which will install the /Area/Help stuff. I guess that it should be updated?

Try what happens if you uninstall the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` and re-install it. Note; if after uninstall of the package the `/Area/Help/**` files are not removed delete those manually, they will be returned upon reinstall.

Comment: After almost giving up and having reinstalled : this part saved me "if after uninstall of the package the /Area/Help/** files are not removed delete those manually"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you controller inherits from ApiController and not just Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when getting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.

At Nuget Package Manager Console write this:

Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProjectNameGoesHere' -Reinstall
This will update all your packages and it will solve your problem.I hope it helps

Comment: I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Match your package versions install the pre release version of help too:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage -Pre

I hope this helps.