# How can i have multiple GET methods in single Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

```
namespace EmployeeApi.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeDetailsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/employeedetails
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
        {


        }


        public IEnumerable<Details> Get(int id)
        {

        }

        public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeamMember()
        {

        }
        public IEnumerable<Details> GetTid(int id)
        {


        }
}


I would like to have my webApi something like this:

1)  IEnumerable<Employee> Get()         -> api/employeedetails
2)  IEnumerable<Details> Get(int id)    -> api/employeedetails/id
3)  IEnumerable<Team> GetTeamMember()   -> api/employeedetails/id/teammember
4)  IEnumerable<Details> GetTid(int id) -> api/employeedetails/id/teammember/tid
```

I tried making changes to routing, but as I am new to it, could'nt understand much.So, please can some one help me understand and guide me on how this should be done.
    Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).
I prefere to use them as they give an easy overview on how the routing is configured when reading the controllers method.

```
namespace EmployeeApi.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeDetailsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/employeedetails
        [Route("api/employeedetails")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
        {

        }

        // GET api/employeedetails/1
        [Route("api/employeedetails/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Details> Get(int id)
        {

        }

        // GET api/employeedetails/id/teammember
        [Route("api/employeedetails/id/teammember")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeamMember()
        {

        }

        // GET api/employeedetails/id/teammember/1
        [Route("api/employeedetails/id/teammember/{tid}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Details> GetTid(int tid)
        {


        }
}
```

You can also use RoutePrefix on top of the controller that specifies the prefix for the controller route, in your case the "api/employeedetails". You can find more details in the "Route Prefixes" section in the link

Comment: i am getting this error...XmlDocumentationProvider does not implement interface member GetDocumentation

Comment: @MahekMerchant Try the solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295078/error-when-upgrading-to-webapi-2-1-xmldocumentationprovider-does-not-implement-i

Comment: How do i remove Controller name...i want api/Get instead of api/employeedetails/Get

Comment: @MahekMerchant Write it in the route as this: [Route("api/Get")]

Answer (score 0):

After the list of relevant comments has grown, I'll restructure my original answer now.

If you're not able to use attribute routing as suggested in Marcus' answer (see my update statement at the bottom), you need to configure your routes (probably in the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file). You can try the following code there:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetEmployeeDetails",
            url: "api/employeedetails",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "GetEmployees" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetEmployeeDetailsById",
            url: "api/employeedetails/{employeeId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "GetDetails", employeeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetTeamMember",
            url: "api/employeedetails/{employeeId}/teammember",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "GetTeams", employeeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetTeamMemberById",
            url: "api/employeedetails/{employeeId}/teammember/{teamId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "GetDetailsForTeam", employeeId = UrlParameter.Optional, teamId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

There'll probably be more routes (for example a generic default route) and also routes to be ignored, but this is out if scope for this question.

These routes correspond with the following action methods within your controller class:

```
public class EmployeeDetailsController : Controller
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        // Get your list of employees here

        return ...;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Detail> GetDetails(int employeeId = 0)
    {
        // Get your list of details here

        return ...;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams(int employeeId = 0)
    {
        // Get your list of teams here

        return ...;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Detail> GetDetailsForTeam(int employeeId = 0, int teamId = 0)
    {
        // Get your list of details here

        return ...;
    }
}
```

There is a chance that you do not need the `employeeId` parameter for the `GetDetailsForTeam()` method, since maybe the `teamId` is sufficient to get the desired information. If that is the case you can remove the parameter from the action method **and** the corresponding route.

These route configurations are pretty straightforward. Each route needs a unique name, otherwise you'll end up with a runtime error. The url - well - contains the url that route is supposed to handle. And after that you can specify the controller name, the action method to be called (these are your `Get` methods) and their respective parameters.

A word or two regarding naming conventions: In a controller named `EmployeeDetailsController` I would expect every "generically named" action method to return one or many `EmployeeDetails` objects (or their respective `ActionResult`s). Therefore, a simple `Get()` method should return one or many `EmployeeDetails` objects.

In case you want to return objects of different types I would choose specific names (as suggested in my code above). In your case that would be a `GetEmployees()` method, a `GetDetails(int employeeId = 0)` method, a `GetTeams(int employeeId = 0)` method and a `GetDetailsForTeam(int employeeId = 0, int teamId = 0)` method. Note the optional parameters here.

If you have these methods in place I'd start with the routing. You need to make sure that each route can be connected to exactly one action method; that's why I asked for the complete URL in one of the comments. If you keep getting the "multiple actions were found" error, you're route URLs are not configured in such a way.

Also please note that route order does matter, though in your example I don't see any conflicting routes.

**UPDATE:** As an alternative you could use attribute routing, where you put the desired route directly into an attribute of your action method inside the controller. But for this to work with ASP.NET MVC 4 you'd need to install the [AttributeRouting NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting).

Comment: GetTid function needs only tid as a single parameter

Comment: Then you would probably have to rename that parameter to `tid` in your function declaration. But what about the `id` in both the `teammember` URLs? Are those not IDs with actual values?

Comment: Hierarchy should be like this
1)emloyeedetails should display list of empid, 
2)employeedetails/id should display detail information of particular empid
3)employeeddetails/id/teammember should display if that empid has teammembers or not

Comment: 4)employeedetails/id/teammember/tid should display details of team members of that empid

Comment: So your `GetTid` function **does** need both the `id` and the `tid` parameter, right? How else would you get the desired information?

Comment: after configuring as you said...still getting same error.................. Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EmployeeApi.Models.Employee] Get() on type EmployeeApi.Controllers.EmployeeDetailsController System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EmployeeApi.Models.Team] GetTeamMember() on type EmployeeApi.Controllers.EmployeeDetailsController

Comment: What was the request? Which URL did you try?

Comment: Also: Does your `GetTeamMember` function need the `id` parameter? It's not there in your code, but in the route configuration.

Comment: in url:/api/employeedetails........Get and GetTeamMember are conflicting......both do not have parameters

Comment: You can absolutely have multiple action methods without any parameters in one controller, as long as they have different names. I will, however, update my answer and include some naming information.

Comment: This is my getEmployees() method......public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
 {  Employee e1 = new Employee();
Employee e2 = new Employee();
Employee e3 = new Employee();
Employee e4 = new Employee();
Employee e5 = new Employee();
List<Employee> li = new List<Employee>();
e1.Name = "Mahek";
e1.Id = 12;
e2.Name = "Ricky";
e2.Id = 56;
e3.Name = "Divya";
e3.Id = 16;
e4.Name = "Nishil";
e4.Id = 77;
e5.Name = "Tarun";
e5.Id = 40;
  li.Add(e1);
  li.Add(e2);
  li.Add(e3);
  li.Add(e4);  li.Add(e5);
 return li;
  }

Comment: This is my getTeamMember()..... public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeamMember()
        {
            Team t1 = new Team();
            
            List<Team> li = new List<Team>();



            t1.TeamName = "Testing";
            t1.Member1 = 45;
            t1.Member2 = 78;
            t1.Member3 = 41;
            li.Add(t1);


            return li;

        }

Comment: Those are both hard to read here, but I don't think the method content even matters. The problem occurs before the methods even get called. As I said, you probably need to get your action method signatures straight and then build the routes accordingly.

Comment: I restructured my answer a little and added some controller code. This should actually provide a fully working example.

Comment: Thanks man...:)..jst one more thing how do i remove controller name from url...i want api/GetEmployees instead of api/employeedetails/GetEmployees...and when i remove default route ...it generates 404 error

Comment: You need to configure the url within the route configuration. Try `url: "api/GetEmployees",` there. But if removing the default route results in a 404, it seems that your route configuration is still off. Hard to tell, though.